# Android Studio Gradle: complile library with required flavor

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, android-studio

I am trying to use a Library from a Module, but built that library in specified Flavor.

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':library_module_1')
    compile project(':library_module_2', configuration: 'flavor_1')
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are your symptoms? Also note that `flavor_1` would not appear to be a build variant, whereas [the documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Library-Publication) uses `flavor1Release`, which *would* appear to be a build variant.

Comment: Symptoms are very generic Error:(90, 0) Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'project()'! ...